# iterable in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have:

```
usernames = [user.get('username') for user in json.loads(users)]
```

Will the json.loads be called once as in normal for loop or many times on each iteration?

Comment: The answers is clear, but your examples suggests that `users` is JSON string. Is this just for the example? Could you please show more context where/how `users` come into play? Does it come from a file or response from e.g. API

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with strings and yes, it's for the example. Was wondering if I can skip the loop and use comprehension for readability, now I know. Thank you all.

Comment: Next time, to test yourself, just make an iterable function that prints out whenever it's called and use that.

Comment: @ivko If the answers below answer your question, then you should perhaps see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be called only once as in a normal for-loop. For example:

```py
x = [2,4,6,8,10]
y = [i/2 for i in x]
```

Output:

```py
>>> y
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Here each element of `x` is called once as `i` and divided by 2 as `i/2`. Similarly, `json.loads(users)` will also be called once.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry: it is called only once, although the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) isn't exactly clear on this point:

> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one for clause and zero or more for or if clauses. In this case, the elements of the new container are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce an element each time the innermost block is reached.